# Verifying coordinates against a map

Tags: android, google-maps

There are some coordinates. How do I verify this is within the boundaries of the map coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`MapView.getMapCenter`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#getMapCenter%28%29). Together with  [`MapView.getLatitudeSpan()`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#getLatitudeSpan%28%29) and [`MapView.getLongitudeSpan()`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#getLongitudeSpan%28%29) you'll be able to calculate the map boundaries in latitude/longitude coordinates.